# mysql cannot find database after dropped of it and restored

Tags: mysql

Due to some errors   I decided to drop of all schema and then restore db structure from dump file.  After restoration all other mysql server clients cannot find it (error 1164 ). Only mysqlworkbench   root@localhost I can see that db. 
Using same connection data @localhost other clients cannot find that db.

Comment: Have you granted those users the necessary permissions on the database?

Comment: Might be better on server fault or dba stack exchange

Comment: Are you sure you mean [error 1164](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_table_cant_handle_auto_increment) "*The used table type doesn't support AUTO_INCREMENT columns*"??

Comment: Probably *ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'missing.table' doesn't exist...* which definitely points to missing grants *if* the schema and table are really there and visible to another user.

Answer (score 1):

From the root account do:

> show grants for data@'localhost';

If it's empty then re-add the grants. Your dump file probably didn't contact the MYSQL db so it didn't restore the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the permissions on the files to make sure mysql is the owner:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql yourdatadir
```

Comment: If the database were restored from a dump file and visible to any user, the permissions on the data directory shouldn't be an issue.  The username "root" has no intrinsic meaning within MySQL and doesn't correlate to any OS-level "root" privilege.